# Set handler for PDF in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, httphandler

I developed an `HttpHandler` in order to count number of downloads for PDF files.

Now the problem is: How can I make IIS use my handler for PDF files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For IIS 7 it does depend on which mode you are running IIS in. Microsoft has a great tutorial on this [How to: Register HTTP Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which goes over all the different configuration scenarios but assuming you are running IIS 7 in integrated mode and your handler is a compiled binary you would need a web.config entry similar to the following:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="pdfCountHandler" verb="*" 
        path="*.pdf" 
        type="<your handler class name>, <your handler assembly name>" 
        resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```