# ASP.NET - Check Session Before Opening a File

Tags: asp.net, session

My question is, Can I Check session before allowing user to view a file, e.g:

http://www.somedomain/pdf/dummy.pdf

When user clicks on this url I want to check whether the session is valid or not, If session is valid allow user to view/download the file otherwise take the user to Login page.

Thanks.

Comment: Post some code please

Comment: Post some code for what? I asking how can it be done.

Comment: how you are allowing user to view file

Comment: you don't need to do anything special to let user view the, if you have the URL user can view it, e.g http://google.uci.edu/images/googleicon.png

Comment: your question has two parts one for reading file read this http://dotnetslackers.com/community/blogs/haissam/archive/2007/04/03/Downloading-Files-C_2300_.aspx and second for checking session on click event you can check in if esle condition

Comment: Dude...I think you didn't understand the question

Comment: try this http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/122/Simple-File-Download-Protection-with-ASP.NET

Comment: Can you make your question more specific what you want?

Comment: You don't give them direct access to files, you use a function which will give a Response with that file - that way you don't give them direct file access,.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I wanted to do. Thank to: @skhurams

http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/122/Simple-File-Download-Protection-with-ASP.NET

Answer (score 3):

You can write [HttpHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986(v=vs.100).aspx) and set it to process *.pdf files. `IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest` method has access to `HttpContext` so you can access session information and do pretty much all you want...

How to setup handler for PDF files depends on IIS version but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14848527/set-handler-for-pdf-in-iis)'s an example of doing it via Web.config file for IIS 7 in integrated mode. For versions prior to 7, Web.config file change is not enough, you also have to use IIS Manager to map extension to `Aspnet_isapi.dll`. Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb515343%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for details.

Your question is a bit vogue. Maybe you don't want to access `HttpSessionState`, instead you just want to use standard ASP.NET URL authentication on static files (such as PDF)? If so, search for "ASP.NET authorization for static files", this is quite popular topic.